# Add configurable product to grouped product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, grouped-products

I want to add configurable product to grouped product but when I search magento show me only simple product. How to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not come with this option by default, but someone else has created an extension:

[Grouped Options by BRIM](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/grouped-options.html) does exactly what you are looking for. I have bought and tried it out but we ended up going in a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

Magento **Grouped Products** are just a collection of **Simple** products. You are not able to have products with custom options (Configurable Products) inside a Grouped Product.

More details here: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-grouped.html